# How to implement a global exception handling in Raku Cro Application

Tags: raku, cro

I am working with a rather larger Cro application with dozens of routes, models and other logic. At the moment in each route block is a `CATCH` to handle exception. That is not much maintenance friendly, not to speak of the work to add them.
So, I was wondering if its a better way to do that. One `CATCH` handler in the main route block does not work. The exceptions are only caught in the route block where they are thrown. Threading issue probably.
Is there one place where I can implement an exception handler which gets all exceptions and can handle them without causing the application to die?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `around` function in your `route` block to specify something that wraps around all of the route handlers. The [documentation of `around`](https://cro.services/docs/reference/cro-http-router#Wrapping_route_handlers) gives an example of using it to handle exceptions thrown by all route handlers in the `route` block (repeated here for convenience):

```
my $application = route {
    around -> &handler {
        # Invoke the route handler
        handler();
        CATCH {
            # If any handler produces this exception...
            when Some::Domain::Exception::UpdatingOldVersion {
                # ...return a HTTP 409 Conflict response.
                conflict;
            }
        }
    }

    # Put your get, post, etc. here.
}
```